# Access and SQL: how to link dates to SELECT statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working in Access in forms.
I want to calculate a price change in a commodity, which is selected by a user from a list, over a date range, which is also selected by a user from lists.
Layout of the user dashboard is shown below:
[image]

Let's say a user selects Supplier BBB in the first list box (then clicks refresh so the second list box gets populated), then selects part BEC1 (refresh), a date range (01/01/15-02/01/16) (refresh) and then the commodity copper (refresh). 
I then want the non-red list box to show the copper price change from 01/01/15 - 02/01/16.

I don't know how to code a dynamic calculation function in a query or Access where all data is pretty much varying user input. 
Note: The supplier, material and date data come from the union of two tables: one called Item Master another called ZMCE. The commodity, commodity prices and commodity dates linked to those prices can be found in table CommPrices.

I envision something like this

```
SELECT ((CommPrices.Price1 - CommPrices.Price0)/CommPrices.Price0) 
FROM CommPrices
WHERE CommPrices.CommDate >= [Forms]![FormName]![ListBox3a] and CommPrices.CommDate <= [Forms]![FormName]![Listbox3b];
```

Where I'm mostly stuck is how to link a date to the commodity prices. All prices are in one column, so I don't know how to differentiate between a price at point 01/01/15 and a price at point 02/01/16. **EDIT: the list of dates above are not necessarily the same as the dates for commodity prices. I just want to calculate the change for the closest dates then.**

Comment: Is the query listed here not working? I didn't test it but appears correct. Coincidentally, instead of making the user click refresh you could simply add requery code behind the AfterUpdate events of the list boxes. For example, supplier click Supplier BBB in ListBox1. AfterUpdate event has ListBox2.Requery

Comment: I didn't test the query since I believe it to be wrong anyway given the fact I don't know how to define my price range. Is putting a 0 and 1 behind the column name clear enough for the code to know that 0 refers to the oldest date and 1 refers to the most recent date? Thank you for the refresh alternative suggestion!

Comment: I missed that part, no that will not work, you can't append the 0 and 1 to the column names, they need to match what is in the table. So I understand correctly, are you looking for the price change specifically between the 2 dates selected? Ie ...(price on day 1/1/15 - price on day 2/1/16) / price on day 2/1/16)

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As with everything there are multiple ways of doing this. Here is an example of an easy way to do this with multiple queries.

Query One (sel_PriceFrom) - Get Price for ListBox3a

```
SELECT CommPrices.Price AS PriceFrom
FROM CommPrices
WHERE (((CommPrices.CommDate)=[Forms]![Form1]![ListBox3a]));
```

Query Two - (sel_PriceTo) - Get Price for ListBox3b

```
SELECT CommPrices.Price AS PriceTo
FROM CommPrices
WHERE (((CommPrices.CommDate)=[Forms]![Form1]![ListBox3b]));
```

Query 3 - using Query1 and 2 as sources, return Price Change

```
SELECT ([PriceFrom]-[PriceTo])/[PriceTo] AS PriceChange
FROM sel_PriceFrom, sel_PriceTo;
```

Comment: This works almost completely, thank you! The only issue I have is that the dates in the commodity table are not necessarily the same dates in the list of dates the user can choose from. So I put <= and >= in the queries you wrote above, for the date part. But now I get a list of different values while I only want one value.

Comment: Why don't you set the RowSource for the combo box's to the same table? You could do something like Select Distinct CommDate from CommPrices Order BY CommDate .... then the dates would match.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand. The table with commodity prices has a date column, the table with supplier transactions also has a date column. There may be transactions recorded for the supplier table at for example 02/02/2016 and 03/03/2016 but we may not have registered the price of a commodity at those dates Yet I want to see what the commodity prices were closet to those transaction dates. (The goal is to see if increases/decreases in commodities influenced supplier transaction prices).